free variables in eigen values and eigen vectors confusion
I have a problem of just simply finding the eigen values and eigen vectors but I am getting confused by the presence of free variables.
So for matrix $B = \begin{pmatrix}3&2&0\\ \:\:2&4&-2\\ \:\:0&-2&5\end{pmatrix}$
I found the eigen values to be $\lambda = 1,4,7$
My problem is finding the eigen vectors:
for $\lambda = 1$, I have to solve $(B - \lambda I)v = 0 $
so I am solving:
$\begin{pmatrix}2&2&0\\ \:\:\:2&3&-2\\ \:\:\:0&-2&4\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a\\ \:\:\:b\\ \:\:\:c\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\ \:\:0\\ \:\:0\end{pmatrix}$
$a = b$, $b = \frac{2}{3}c - \frac{2}{3}a$ and $b = 2c$ or $c = \frac{1}{2}b$
which one is the free variable here and what does the eigen vector looks like?
Since $a = b$ is $a$ the free variable? So can I just leave $ a$ as it is?
Here is my confusion: I have $a = b$ and I have $b = \frac{2}{3}c - \frac{2}{3}a$
but I know I could solve $b$ in terms of $a$ by expressing $c$ in terms of $a$? or should I just simply use $b = a$
so solving $b$ in terms of $a$ I get:
$v = \begin{pmatrix}1\\ -\frac{1}{3}a\\ \frac{1}{2}a\end{pmatrix}$

Find one by setting $a=1$ for example. Then you find all of them since they are all parallel. I don’t know how you computed your end result, it seems false

The part where you compute $(B-\lambda I)v=0$ is correct. However, the computation for the eigenvectors is incorrect.
There are two methods to compute your eigenvectors. Let consider your example above, eigenvalue $\lambda=1$.
Method 1:
$$
(B-I)=0
$$
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 
2 & 2 & 0 \\
2 & 3 & -2 \\  
0 & -2 & 4 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 
x \\
y \\  
z \\
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix} 
0 \\
0 \\  
0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Apply gaussian elimination:
$$
\begin{matrix}
\\
-R_1 + R_2 \rightarrow\\
\\
\end{matrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 
2 & 2 & 0 \\
2 & 3 & -2 \\  
0 & -2 & 4 \\
\end{bmatrix} \Longrightarrow
\begin{bmatrix} 
2 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & -2 \\  
0 & -2 & 4 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
We arrive at three equations and three unknowns:
$$
\begin{align*} 
2x+2y&=0 & (I) \\
y-2z&=0 & (II)\\  
-2y+4z&=0 & (III)\\
\end{align*}
$$
You can see from the above equations $(II)$ and $(III)$ are linear combinations of each other. This implies solving for:
$$
\begin{align*} 
x&=-y \\
y&=2z \\
\end{align*}
$$
From the above, we can observe that $z$ is the free variable.
$$
\begin{align*} 
x&=-y=-2z \\
y&=2z \\
z&=z
\end{align*}
$$
Solving for the unknowns, and letting $z=t$ such that $ t \in \mathbb{R}$,
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 
x \\
y \\  
z \\
\end{bmatrix} = t
\begin{bmatrix} 
-2 \\
2 \\  
1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Hence, the eigenvector $v = (-2, 2, 1)^T$ corresponding to $\lambda=1$.
The next method can be only used for eigensystem in $\mathbb{R}^3$.
Method 2:
Consider any two linearly independent columns for $(B-\lambda I)v=0$ and take the cross-product. We can choose columns 1 and 2 for this case.
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 
2 \\
2 \\  
0 \\
\end{bmatrix} \times
\begin{bmatrix} 
2 \\
3 \\  
-2 \\
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix} 
-4 \\
4 \\  
2 \\
\end{bmatrix} = 2
\begin{bmatrix} 
-2 \\
2 \\  
1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Hence, we arrived at the same answer. $v = (-2, 2, 1)^T$ corresponding to $\lambda=1$.
Do the same for the other eigenvalues. Hope it helps.

Thanks, I understand now !
